# How can I target Android 4.1 in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I have VS2017 and VS2019 installed side by side on my Windows 10 machine.

I can not compile Xamarin Android 4.1 projects (in VS2019) unless I upgrade them to 4.4 which seems to be the minimum Android SDK version I can target in VS2019. VS2017 compiles fine.

If I create a new Xamarin Android project in VS2019 I can select from 4.4 and above, but in VS2017 I can target right back to 2.3. 
Both Visual Studio Xamarin settings are pointing to the same location for the android-sdk (which is on my D: drive, but I did copy it to the standard install location to verify it was not using this as a default, which made no difference)

**VS2019 Minimum Android Version**

[image: VS2019 Minimum Android Version]

**VS2017 Minimum Android Version**

[image: VS2017 Minimum Android Version]

Is it possible to target Android 4.1 using VS2019?

Comment: That is probably because they are obsolete? Why do you plan on targetting them anyway! I do not believe that there are a lot of devices left that use that anyway.

Comment: Not planning to use. Am using currently. The devices are running an old android, yes. They are specialised ruggedised tablets that are part of a product range. Just because consumer devices are running the latest and greatest does not mean everyone are. We have plans to upgrade but it's low priority when compared to features etc.

Comment: Have you tried to see if you can run the app on 4.1 although it is targeted for 4.4?

Comment: @JohnDalsgaard The device will not even be shown in the list it will be available separately as unsupported devices!

Comment: @StephenPrice If that is the case not to be rude or something you should be using 2017 because it will not work for you in 2019, it is not like a configuration that you can change, secondly if you ever had 2015 you would know it supported even below 2.3, I hope you get the hint!

Comment: In my VS2019 I can target even Android 1.6, API Level 4 - Dounat, so it should be possible.

Comment: Ah so seems I have become confused between target api version, and compiled with sdk version. Selecting 4.4 (or higher) still lets the project compile fine, and the main project can still choose 4.1 in Minimum Android Version (and Target Android Version) so it should run fine. Compiling with a newer SDK should be ok. I will document this in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following when making decisions with your Android versions:

```
minSdkVersion (lowest possible) <= 
    targetSdkVersion == compileSdkVersion/TargetFrameworkVersion (latest SDK)
```

It's also worthwhile to consider the Android Dashboard to understand how many devices are running a specific version of Android.

https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards

Answer (score 0):

Selecting a higher "Compile using Android version" still lets the project compile.

Under the Android Manifest tab, you can still select the older Minimum and Target Android version allowing VS2019 to be used with this solution/project that uses an older Target Version.

Per the tooltip, Target Framework is only used at runtime.

[image: Android Manifest]