# Visual Studio 2019 Mac: How to set minimum Android Version of API level 14?

Tags: android, macos, visual-studio, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

I am using Visual Studio 2019 for Mac. On my android project the minimum API level I can select is API level 19. I don't understand why the lowest level is only level 19 - I'd like to select 14. Anyone knows why the lowest available level is level 19?

[image]

Comment: Related but OP used Windows 10: [How can I target Android 4.1 in Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55945365/how-can-i-target-android-4-1-in-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: There is an option called API level 10 in my minimum android version option list. I use Visual-Studio-Mac 8.3.11.